# Pdf display using HTML5 with Object Amazon S3

Tags: html, scala, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3

I am trying to display a pdf file that I stored in a bucket in Amazon S3

This is the code

```
<object data="@{pdf.route}" type="application/pdf" style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
  <p>Link Alternativo  <a href="@{pdf.route}">Descarga el PDF!</a></p>
</object>
```

The value of the parameter `@{pdf.route}` is the route for a service that I have in scala to get the file, because is not public.
If the value of the parameter `@{pdf.route}` is pasted on a browser it will ask you if you want to download the file. But, it doesn't show on the page.

Comment: First guess is that the PDF was not uploaded to S3 with `Content-Type: application/pdf`, so the browser doesn't *know* that it's a PDF.  Check this? (in the console)

Comment: Thank you very much @Michael-sqlbot, you were right. If you want, please publish as the answer and I will mark as the correct answer